# How to i skip history?

Tags: linux, bash, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid to keep command in history](https://serverfault.com/questions/48769/avoid-to-keep-command-in-history)

Is there a facility to skip history for some commands in Linux?

How can I skip history for a login?

When I login as user `abc`, I don't want my machine to save commands history for user `abc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use export the `HISTIGNORE` variable for this user. Have a look at [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/).
To make it permanent, you need to export it in a file like `~/.bashrc`.